# Site scroll bar that appears when you refresh multiple times

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this site ...

http://reliancetrustgroup.com/

If you refresh the page several times you'll see that once a page appears with scroll appears once without scrolling

From what can cause this problem?

```
    .page-id-5 #content{
    height:auto !important;
}
```

I tried adding this code to solve, but unfortunately does not work ... So it is.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Comment: I get the scroll bar every time in Chrome.

Comment: You have an mainPageResize error from main.js on line 63 check this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a scrollbar every time in the latest Chrome on OSX for me.

You can avoid this by adding `height: 100vh;` to your main page container. However, do know that [vh](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) isn't *quite* supported in every browser yet.

Also, if you do this, you'll want to space all of your elements based on percentages or vh units so that if a monitor is shorter, all of the elements fit. You'll also want to remove the `overflow: hidden;` because that may cause information to be hidden.